# Mailer Error on sending mail with Flutter

Tags: email, dart, flutter

I'm actually developping a mobile app with Flutter and I wish I could send an email from it. To do so, i tried to use the Mailer plugin with the following code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mailer2/mailer.dart';

main() {

    var options = new GmailSmtpOptions()
      ..username = 'mer*******@gmail.com'
      ..password = '*******';

    var emailTransport = new SmtpTransport(options);

    // Create our mail/envelope.
    var envelope = new Envelope()
      ..from = 'mer*******@gmail.com'
      ..recipients.add('*******@*****.fr')
      ..subject = 'Testing the Dart Mailer library'
      ..text = 'This is a cool email message. Whats up? 語'
      ..html = '<h1>Test</h1><p>Hey!</p>';

    // Email it.
    emailTransport.send(envelope)
        .then((envelope) => print('Email sent!'))
        .catchError((e) => print('Error occurred: $e'));
}
```

However, i have the following error:

```
I/flutter (22531): Error occurred: type '_AsBroadcastStream<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<Envelope>' where
I/flutter (22531):   _AsBroadcastStream is from dart:async
I/flutter (22531):   Stream is from dart:async
I/flutter (22531):   Envelope is from package:mailer/mailer.dart
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please check if mailer plugin is updated after flutter got updated.. could be that the plugin is old and is not compatible with new flutter.

Comment: Looks like it's a known Dart 2 issue. https://github.com/kaisellgren/mailer/issues/42 From the Dart command line it works unless you set `--preview-dart-2`. Flutter sets that flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this file

> mailer-1.1.4/lib/src/smtp/**smtp_client.dart**

Update lines 49 & 50 by add "cast()" method to be:

`onIdle = _onIdleController.stream.asBroadcastStream().cast();
    onSend = _onSendController.stream.asBroadcastStream().cast();`